# Failed to Migrate Windows Boot Manager

Tags: dell-poweredge, windows-server-2022, boot-loader

I have a **Dell PowerEdge R720** server running **Windows Server 2022 Datacenter** on a SATA SSD. Due to a disk corruption incident, there are bad tracks on the old system disk, but it still functions. To ensure data integrity, I migrated the system to a new SATA SSD. I cloned the system partition to a new SATA SSD using DiskGenius system migration utility and added a boot entry using `bcdboot`. The cloned system successfully boots. However, upon removing the old corrupted disk, the system displays "No boot device available."

[image: No boot device available]

I realized that the BIOS was relying on the Windows Boot Manager on the old disk during the last successful boot. To resolve this, I've attempted the following:

- Cloned the MBR partition from the old disk to the new one.
- Booted to the new system, formatted the MBR partition on the new disk and ran `bcdboot C:\Windows /s X: /f BIOS` (with X as the drive letter assigned to the MBR partition on the new disk).

Unfortunately, none of these methods have worked, and I'm now stuck and seeking guidance on how to make the new disk bootable.

Note: DiskGenius system migration utility migrated the MBR partition along with the operating system, but it failed to work for unknown reasons.

Comment: Odd, I've cloned SATA HDD -> SATA SSD (no difference to what you're doing, SATA to SATA) about 2 dozen times, and never had to fiddle with bcdboot or any thing - it just worked - perhaps because you booted with both disks in the system at the same time it caused windows to have a hernia

Comment: Does the old disk still boot?

Comment: Forget what you know about MBR. Modern machines boot using UEFI. You have a small UEFI partition, and [windows boot manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcd-system-store-settings-for-uefi?view=windows-11) must be known to UEFI firmware.

Comment: This is exactly the same as your previous episode.  Sometimes old hardware fails. https://serverfault.com/questions/1123049/unable-to-boot-after-cloning-windows-server-datacenter-2022-to-a-new-ssd

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, the old disk still boots

Comment: @GregAskew To some extent, yes, I'm still stuck on the same server for the same purpose. You could say I made some progress on this matter and faced a new problem. But they are not the same question.

Comment: I'd try a different duplication method ... I used clonezilla when upgrading hdd to ssd ... after cloning, remove the old drive, boot into new drive

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the installation media again and under advanced options start a command prompt and try to repair the boot manager with these commands

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The last command throws "the requested system device cannot be found"

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something else:
https://www.prime-expert.com/articles/a20/rebuild-efi-system-partition-from-scratch/

I don't know if you have EFI boot or not, but with most operating systems that's the case.